# Testing out PyDev and Checkbutton not working

Tags: python-3.x, pydev

I am wondering why it is that I can run [this code](https://github.com/TDBJR/Study/blob/master/Check_buttons.py) in the normal `python` `idle`, but when I try it in `pydev` nothing happens.

I just installed `pydev` and as far as I can tell I told it to use the same `Python 3.5` version that I was using before. Any advice is appreciated.

For installation, I followed [these directions](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/common/handouts/pythoneclipsejava/eclipsepython.html) except I installed `Eclipse Neon` with `PyDev 5.4` and I have `Python 3.5.2`

When Run it in `Pydev` with `ctrl+F11` it gives:

```
< terminated >Check_buttons.py[C;\user\Thomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python35\python.exe]]
```

When I run it with `F11` (*debugger*) it gives:

```
< terminated >Check_buttons.py[C;\user\Thomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python35\python.exe]]
pydev debugger:starting (pid:12308)
```

**EDIT:**

Looks like in PyDev root.mainloop has to have() while in the normal
idle it does not.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide more information, so your question would become more "answerable". What exactly do you see when you run your code in PyDev? Do you run in debug mode? How exactly were you setting up Python version and environment?

Comment: Usually for running you'd just use F9 on PyDev (with a focus on the editor). See: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_run.html

Comment: I'm able to run windows created from Tkinter unless they include Checkbuttons. I even tried    from Tkinter import Checkbutton